# Axios Create Error when making a POST Request from an ExpressJS Application

Tags: express, axios

I'm not sure what might be the issue, but whenever I try to make a post request from my express application, I keep getting a create Error as response from axios.

First off my VS Code hinted that `post` does not exist on axios.

Here is my code

```
const axios = require('axios');
 let oAuthRequestTokenURL = `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`;
 axios.post(oAuthRequestTokenURL, {}).then((response) => {
            let initialTokenResponse = response.data;
            console.log(`ResponseData=${JSON.stringify(initialTokenResponse, null, 2)}`);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Here is the error message I keep getting back

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157656+00:00 app[web.1]:     at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157656+00:00 app[web.1]:     at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157657+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157658+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:406:35)
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157658+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157658+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157659+00:00 app[web.1]:   config: {
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157659+00:00 app[web.1]:     url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157660+00:00 app[web.1]:     method: 'post',
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157660+00:00 app[web.1]:     headers: {
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157660+00:00 app[web.1]:       Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157660+00:00 app[web.1]:       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157661+00:00 app[web.1]:       'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
2021-09-15T12:47:14.157661+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
```

What could be wrong?
Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Comment: If you're getting a 400 error, it sounds like your request just isn't set up correctly.

Comment: You did not send any parameters with you request, did you? See [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token) for which parameters are required.